# Manuals vs certification plates

Tags: power, voltage, frequency, safety, certification

If a device manual with a stated model reads 220-240V 50/60 Hz must the certifcation tag match?

Is this different on a per country basis? (In this case Germany)

For example this manual excerpt:

[this one http://www.imagesup.net/?di=014105027451](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=014105027451)

Does the device tag need to match exact?

Comment: It's not my area of expertise but I believe this varies a lot by country. For example my understanding is that I could import that item into Australia legally for my own use (at my own risk) but it would be illegal for me to sell them. However I could get it tested and if approved attach a certification label and sell them.

Comment: I know in Canada insurance claims can be denied with out underwriters labratory (UL) testing on my dime. I don't think I can legaly use them with out that either.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an example of where the manual doesn't appear to match the product label, some switch mode power supplies may be labelled 100 volts to 230 volts but UL testing and CSA testing will be 15% above and below those values and, the manual is quite at liberty to give the fuller range ie 85 volts to 264 volts. I've seen this just recently and had it confirmed by the reputable supplier.

Comment: So long as the values given are met then? A 50g bag of chip can have 55g but not 45g?

Comment: @beast I don't understand your question/comment. Sorry.

Comment: I am thinking in you example it is ok because the range is larger.  If the range was smaller, say 110-215 volts, do you think UL or CSA would certify the device?